# Part assortments for creative building

Tags: building, sets

I've been shifting away from collecting sets to doing more MOC building. I also recently moved and I'd like to reduce the overall size of my LEGO collection. I'm trying to decide which parts I'd like to get rid of and which parts I'd like to keep.

I'm interested in keeping large numbers of versatile parts while selling off parts that tend to serve a single purpose. I'm hoping to find example part assortments (not necessarily official sets) that are most useful for MOCs and rebuilding.

To explain what I mean, here are two example sets. The first is the new [Architecture Studio](http://brickset.com/detail/?set=21050-1) set:

[image: Architecture Studio]

The second is the Hobby Train set from 2007:

[image: Hobby Train]

These both contain a good mix of pieces that can be reused in all sorts of models. Are there other sets, parts packs, or lists that provide a good platform for creative building?

Comment: I believe a lot of creator sets would fit your description; they tend to be good packs of assorted parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It very much depends on how and what you like to build so personal recommendations are difficult. As you're new-ish to MOCing it may take some time to figure out what pieces you like the most.

That said, I'll offer a suggestion - I find 10230 Mini Modulars and interesting range of small pieces in various colours incuding some rare ones. Check out the [inventory](http://www.brickset.com/detail/inventory/?Set=10230-1) to see if it appeals to you too. I'd also suggest looking at the Creator sets in general.

[image]